# High workloads cause Stored Procedure to slow down

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-performance

We are running a MySQL server 5.6.40 (InnoDB) using AWS and RDS, our instance class is currently db.t2.medium, which has 4gb RAM.

We have a complex stored procedure that typically takes 1 second to execute.

However we are finding that when the MySQL server instance is under load, and we are receiving higher number of requests (queries), the query time for the stored procedure is taking longer, in most cases anywhere between 3 and 5 seconds.

Where should I start to try and optimise the performance so that irrelevant of the number of requests, the actual query time remains around 1 second.

Comment: Keep in mind that a stored procedure is not a silver bullet for performance, it depends what you are doing if using a stored procedure is justified to use..

Comment: *"Where should I start to try and optimise the performance so that irrelevant of the number of requests, the actual query time remains around 1 second."* You could start by posting the stored procedure code and `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` command for every table the stored procedure uses.. As without the question is simply unclear/to broad and will be most likely voteclosed.

Comment: Typically the server CPU usage averages 20%.  But when there are a high number of requests, the query time is taking longer like in my question, and the CPU spikes and maintains around 60%-70% until the load has reduced.

Comment: Sounds like you will need to [scale/optimize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-optimize-cpu.html) up CPU cores/power, i would suggest contacting amazon support.. As this question is not really [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here or in the gray area as it seams a "hardware" problem

Comment: The SP is composed of some number of queries.  Many things can slow down a query.  However, often the best approach is to try to improve the speed of the query.  Sometimes it is as simple as adding a 'composite' index.  We really need to see the queries and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to help.

Comment: Side-note: It is not recommended to use T-family instances for production usage. They are best used for bursty workloads rather than sustained workloads. See: [CPU Credits and Baseline Performance for Burstable Performance Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html)

Comment: @neildt Be a GOOD SPORT and post the stored procedure code and SHOW CREATE TABLE table command for every table the stored procedure uses. Also post TEXT results of SHOW INDEX FROM each table used so we can see your column cardinality.  With no additional information, we can not provide any useful tips.

Comment: @neildt        No additional information (requested Sep 25, 2019) = no new suggestions.